# Finding the number of digits in a given base in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, integer, logarithm

say we are given numbers n and b where b is the base to be taken, to find the number of digits in n i know that the formula is

⌊logmN⌋+1

however when i try it in haskell by doing

```
(logBase b n)+1
```

i get the answer in float but i want it in int. I am trying to use

```
integerLogBase b n
```

but thats also not working

some examples are that number of digits in 7 in base 2 is 3.

Answer (score 4):

Your notation correctly uses the floor function; you just need to add that to your code: `floor (logBase b n) + 1`